# Where does the kernel keep the serial port config?

Tags: serial-port

I use `echo xxx > /dev/ttySxxx` to send command to tty. When I do this first time, I must set baut rate. After once, I needn't. So, where does the kernel keep the serial port config?

Answer (score -1):

On Debian I found a copy of /etc/serial.conf in /var/lib/setserial.
After using

```
# dpkg-reconfigure setserial
```

the /etc/serial.conf is gone, and appears in /var/lib/setserial/etc.serial.conf

Comment: That's not where the _kernel_ keeps things, though.

Comment: Another place is /proc/tty/driver/serial - only root could see it.
In meaning that you set Baud rate it is stored in the UART chip (UART has several settings what could be changed and stored until you want to modify). Initial setup (boot time - using setserial) was stored in /etc/serial.conf, and now seem, to me in /var/lib/setserial too.